# yum update dosn't work on centos7

Tags: centos, command-line, yum

I have installed centos 7 on a virtual host (I have used the minimal install and automatically partition).

When I have connected to my host and try to update using `yum update` the command dosn't seems to be completed, it display dependancy resolved and the terminal is blocked!!  :

PS : yum install epel-release  worked fine

```
[root@zammad ~]# yum update
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.proxad.net
 * epel: mir01.syntis.net
 * extras: mir01.syntis.net
 * updates: mir01.syntis.net
Résolution des dépendances
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Le paquet GeoIP.x86_64 0:1.5.0-13.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet GeoIP.x86_64 0:1.5.0-14.el7 sera utilisé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : geoipupdate pour le paquet : GeoIP-1.5.0-14.el                                                                                        7.x86_64
---> Le paquet NetworkManager.x86_64 1:1.12.0-6.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet NetworkManager.x86_64 1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64 1:1.12.0-6.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64 1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet NetworkManager-team.x86_64 1:1.12.0-6.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet NetworkManager-team.x86_64 1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet NetworkManager-tui.x86_64 1:1.12.0-6.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet NetworkManager-tui.x86_64 1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet alsa-lib.x86_64 0:1.1.6-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet alsa-lib.x86_64 0:1.1.8-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet audit.x86_64 0:2.8.4-4.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet audit.x86_64 0:2.8.5-4.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.8.4-4.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.8.5-4.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet bash.x86_64 0:4.2.46-31.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet bash.x86_64 0:4.2.46-33.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet bind-libs-lite.x86_64 32:9.9.4-72.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet bind-libs-lite.x86_64 32:9.11.4-9.P2.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet bind-license.noarch 32:9.9.4-72.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet bind-license.noarch 32:9.11.4-9.P2.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet binutils.x86_64 0:2.27-34.base.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet binutils.x86_64 0:2.27-41.base.el7_7.3 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet biosdevname.x86_64 0:0.7.3-1.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet biosdevname.x86_64 0:0.7.3-2.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet ca-certificates.noarch 0:2018.2.22-70.0.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet ca-certificates.noarch 0:2019.2.32-76.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet centos-release.x86_64 0:7-6.1810.2.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet centos-release.x86_64 0:7-7.1908.0.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet coreutils.x86_64 0:8.22-23.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet coreutils.x86_64 0:8.22-24.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet cronie.x86_64 0:1.4.11-19.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet cronie.x86_64 0:1.4.11-23.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet cronie-anacron.x86_64 0:1.4.11-19.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet cronie-anacron.x86_64 0:1.4.11-23.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet cryptsetup-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.3-3.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet cryptsetup-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.3-5.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet curl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-51.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet curl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-54.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dbus.x86_64 1:1.10.24-12.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dbus.x86_64 1:1.10.24-13.el7_6 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dbus-libs.x86_64 1:1.10.24-12.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dbus-libs.x86_64 1:1.10.24-13.el7_6 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet device-mapper.x86_64 7:1.02.149-8.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet device-mapper.x86_64 7:1.02.158-2.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet device-mapper-event.x86_64 7:1.02.149-8.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet device-mapper-event.x86_64 7:1.02.158-2.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.149-8.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.158-2.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet device-mapper-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.149-8.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet device-mapper-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.158-2.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet device-mapper-persistent-data.x86_64 0:0.7.3-3.el7 sera mis à jou                                                                                        r
---> Le paquet device-mapper-persistent-data.x86_64 0:0.8.5-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dhclient.x86_64 12:4.2.5-68.el7.centos.1 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dhclient.x86_64 12:4.2.5-77.el7.centos sera utilisé
--> Traitement de la dépendance : libisc-export.so.169()(64bit) pour le paquet :                                                                                         12:dhclient-4.2.5-77.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Traitement de la dépendance : libdns-export.so.1102()(64bit) pour le paquet                                                                                         : 12:dhclient-4.2.5-77.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Le paquet dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.2.5-68.el7.centos.1 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dhcp-common.x86_64 12:4.2.5-77.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dhcp-libs.x86_64 12:4.2.5-68.el7.centos.1 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dhcp-libs.x86_64 12:4.2.5-77.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet diffutils.x86_64 0:3.3-4.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet diffutils.x86_64 0:3.3-5.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dmidecode.x86_64 1:3.1-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dmidecode.x86_64 1:3.2-3.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dracut.x86_64 0:033-554.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dracut.x86_64 0:033-564.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 0:033-554.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 0:033-564.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet dracut-network.x86_64 0:033-554.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet dracut-network.x86_64 0:033-564.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.42.9-13.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.42.9-16.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.42.9-13.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.42.9-16.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet elfutils-default-yama-scope.noarch 0:0.172-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet elfutils-default-yama-scope.noarch 0:0.176-2.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.172-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.176-2.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet elfutils-libs.x86_64 0:0.172-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet elfutils-libs.x86_64 0:0.176-2.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet epel-release.noarch 0:7-11 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet epel-release.noarch 0:7-12 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet ethtool.x86_64 2:4.8-9.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet ethtool.x86_64 2:4.8-10.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet firewalld.noarch 0:0.5.3-5.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet firewalld.noarch 0:0.6.3-2.el7_7.4 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet firewalld-filesystem.noarch 0:0.5.3-5.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet firewalld-filesystem.noarch 0:0.6.3-2.el7_7.4 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet freetype.x86_64 0:2.8-12.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet freetype.x86_64 0:2.8-14.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet glib2.x86_64 0:2.56.1-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet glib2.x86_64 0:2.56.1-5.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-260.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-292.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-260.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-292.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grub2.x86_64 1:2.02-0.76.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grub2.x86_64 1:2.02-0.80.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grub2-common.noarch 1:2.02-0.76.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grub2-common.noarch 1:2.02-0.80.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grub2-pc.x86_64 1:2.02-0.76.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grub2-pc.x86_64 1:2.02-0.80.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grub2-pc-modules.noarch 1:2.02-0.76.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grub2-pc-modules.noarch 1:2.02-0.80.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grub2-tools.x86_64 1:2.02-0.76.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grub2-tools.x86_64 1:2.02-0.80.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grub2-tools-extra.x86_64 1:2.02-0.76.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grub2-tools-extra.x86_64 1:2.02-0.80.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grub2-tools-minimal.x86_64 1:2.02-0.76.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grub2-tools-minimal.x86_64 1:2.02-0.80.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet grubby.x86_64 0:8.28-25.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet grubby.x86_64 0:8.28-26.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet hostname.x86_64 0:3.13-3.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet hostname.x86_64 0:3.13-3.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet hwdata.x86_64 0:0.252-9.1.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet hwdata.x86_64 0:0.252-9.3.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet initscripts.x86_64 0:9.49.46-1.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet initscripts.x86_64 0:9.49.47-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iproute.x86_64 0:4.11.0-14.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iproute.x86_64 0:4.11.0-25.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iprutils.x86_64 0:2.4.16.1-1.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iprutils.x86_64 0:2.4.17.1-3.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet ipset.x86_64 0:6.38-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet ipset.x86_64 0:7.1-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet ipset-libs.x86_64 0:6.38-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet ipset-libs.x86_64 0:7.1-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iptables.x86_64 0:1.4.21-28.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iptables.x86_64 0:1.4.21-33.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet irqbalance.x86_64 3:1.0.7-11.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet irqbalance.x86_64 3:1.0.7-12.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl100-firmware.noarch 0:39.31.5.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl100-firmware.noarch 0:39.31.5.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl1000-firmware.noarch 1:39.31.5.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl1000-firmware.noarch 1:39.31.5.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl105-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl105-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl135-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl135-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl2000-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl2000-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl2030-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl2030-firmware.noarch 0:18.168.6.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl3160-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl3160-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl3945-firmware.noarch 0:15.32.2.9-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl3945-firmware.noarch 0:15.32.2.9-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl4965-firmware.noarch 0:228.61.2.24-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl4965-firmware.noarch 0:228.61.2.24-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl5000-firmware.noarch 0:8.83.5.1_1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl5000-firmware.noarch 0:8.83.5.1_1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl5150-firmware.noarch 0:8.24.2.2-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl5150-firmware.noarch 0:8.24.2.2-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl6000-firmware.noarch 0:9.221.4.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl6000-firmware.noarch 0:9.221.4.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl6000g2a-firmware.noarch 0:17.168.5.3-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl6000g2a-firmware.noarch 0:17.168.5.3-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl6000g2b-firmware.noarch 0:17.168.5.2-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl6000g2b-firmware.noarch 0:17.168.5.2-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl6050-firmware.noarch 0:41.28.5.1-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl6050-firmware.noarch 0:41.28.5.1-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl7260-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl7260-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet iwl7265-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-69.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet iwl7265-firmware.noarch 0:22.0.7.0-72.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7 sera installé
---> Le paquet kernel-tools.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet kernel-tools.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet kexec-tools.x86_64 0:2.0.15-21.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet kexec-tools.x86_64 0:2.0.15-33.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet kmod.x86_64 0:20-23.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet kmod.x86_64 0:20-25.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet kmod-libs.x86_64 0:20-23.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet kmod-libs.x86_64 0:20-25.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet kpartx.x86_64 0:0.4.9-123.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet kpartx.x86_64 0:0.4.9-127.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet krb5-libs.x86_64 0:1.15.1-34.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet krb5-libs.x86_64 0:1.15.1-37.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libblkid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-59.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libblkid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-61.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libcap.x86_64 0:2.22-9.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libcap.x86_64 0:2.22-10.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libcom_err.x86_64 0:1.42.9-13.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libcom_err.x86_64 0:1.42.9-16.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libcurl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-51.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libcurl.x86_64 0:7.29.0-54.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libdb.x86_64 0:5.3.21-24.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libdb.x86_64 0:5.3.21-25.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libdb-utils.x86_64 0:5.3.21-24.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libdb-utils.x86_64 0:5.3.21-25.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libdrm.x86_64 0:2.4.91-3.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libdrm.x86_64 0:2.4.97-2.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-39.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libgomp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libgomp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-39.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libmount.x86_64 0:2.23.2-59.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libmount.x86_64 0:2.23.2-61.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libndp.x86_64 0:1.2-7.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libndp.x86_64 0:1.2-9.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libsmartcols.x86_64 0:2.23.2-59.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libsmartcols.x86_64 0:2.23.2-61.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libss.x86_64 0:1.42.9-13.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libss.x86_64 0:1.42.9-16.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libssh2.x86_64 0:1.4.3-12.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libssh2.x86_64 0:1.8.0-3.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.8.5-39.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libteam.x86_64 0:1.27-5.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libteam.x86_64 0:1.27-9.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet libuuid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-59.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet libuuid.x86_64 0:2.23.2-61.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet linux-firmware.noarch 0:20180911-69.git85c5d90.el7 sera mis à jou                                                                                        r
---> Le paquet linux-firmware.noarch 0:20190429-72.gitddde598.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet lshw.x86_64 0:B.02.18-12.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet lshw.x86_64 0:B.02.18-13.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet lvm2.x86_64 7:2.02.180-8.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet lvm2.x86_64 7:2.02.185-2.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet lvm2-libs.x86_64 7:2.02.180-8.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet lvm2-libs.x86_64 7:2.02.185-2.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet lz4.x86_64 0:1.7.5-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet lz4.x86_64 0:1.7.5-3.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet make.x86_64 1:3.82-23.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet make.x86_64 1:3.82-24.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.60-1.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.64-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet microcode_ctl.x86_64 2:2.1-47.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet microcode_ctl.x86_64 2:2.1-53.7.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nspr.x86_64 0:4.19.0-1.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nspr.x86_64 0:4.21.0-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nss.x86_64 0:3.36.0-7.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nss.x86_64 0:3.44.0-7.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nss-pem.x86_64 0:1.0.3-5.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nss-pem.x86_64 0:1.0.3-7.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.36.0-5.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.44.0-8.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.36.0-5.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.44.0-8.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.36.0-7.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.44.0-7.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.36.0-7.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.44.0-7.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet nss-util.x86_64 0:3.36.0-1.el7_5 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet nss-util.x86_64 0:3.44.0-4.el7_7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet numactl-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.9-7.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet numactl-libs.x86_64 0:2.0.12-3.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet openldap.x86_64 0:2.4.44-20.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet openldap.x86_64 0:2.4.44-21.el7_6 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet openssh.x86_64 0:7.4p1-16.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet openssh.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet openssh-clients.x86_64 0:7.4p1-16.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet openssh-clients.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet openssh-server.x86_64 0:7.4p1-16.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet openssh-server.x86_64 0:7.4p1-21.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-19.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-16.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet openssl-libs.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-19.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet parted.x86_64 0:3.1-29.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet parted.x86_64 0:3.1-31.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet passwd.x86_64 0:0.79-4.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet passwd.x86_64 0:0.79-5.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet plymouth.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.31.20140113.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet plymouth.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.32.20140113.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet plymouth-core-libs.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.31.20140113.el7.centos sera m                                                                                        is à jour
---> Le paquet plymouth-core-libs.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.32.20140113.el7.centos sera u                                                                                        tilisé
---> Le paquet plymouth-scripts.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.31.20140113.el7.centos sera mis                                                                                         à jour
---> Le paquet plymouth-scripts.x86_64 0:0.8.9-0.32.20140113.el7.centos sera uti                                                                                        lisé
---> Le paquet policycoreutils.x86_64 0:2.5-29.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet policycoreutils.x86_64 0:2.5-33.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet polkit.x86_64 0:0.112-18.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet polkit.x86_64 0:0.112-22.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet procps-ng.x86_64 0:3.3.10-23.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet procps-ng.x86_64 0:3.3.10-26.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-76.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet python.x86_64 0:2.7.5-86.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet python-firewall.noarch 0:0.5.3-5.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet python-firewall.noarch 0:0.6.3-2.el7_7.4 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-76.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet python-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.5-86.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet python-linux-procfs.noarch 0:0.4.9-4.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet python-linux-procfs.noarch 0:0.4.11-4.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet python-perf.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet python-perf.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet qemu-guest-agent.x86_64 10:2.12.0-2.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet qemu-guest-agent.x86_64 10:2.12.0-3.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet readline.x86_64 0:6.2-10.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet readline.x86_64 0:6.2-11.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet rpm.x86_64 0:4.11.3-35.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet rpm.x86_64 0:4.11.3-40.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet rpm-build-libs.x86_64 0:4.11.3-35.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet rpm-build-libs.x86_64 0:4.11.3-40.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.11.3-35.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.11.3-40.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.11.3-35.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.11.3-40.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.24.0-34.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet rsyslog.x86_64 0:8.24.0-41.el7_7.4 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet selinux-policy.noarch 0:3.13.1-229.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet selinux-policy.noarch 0:3.13.1-252.el7_7.6 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet selinux-policy-targeted.noarch 0:3.13.1-229.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet selinux-policy-targeted.noarch 0:3.13.1-252.el7_7.6 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet sg3_utils.x86_64 0:1.37-17.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet sg3_utils.x86_64 0:1.37-18.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet sg3_utils-libs.x86_64 0:1.37-17.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet sg3_utils-libs.x86_64 0:1.37-18.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet shadow-utils.x86_64 2:4.1.5.1-25.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet shadow-utils.x86_64 2:4.6-5.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet sqlite.x86_64 0:3.7.17-8.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet sqlite.x86_64 0:3.7.17-8.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet sudo.x86_64 0:1.8.23-3.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet sudo.x86_64 0:1.8.23-4.el7_7.2 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet systemd.x86_64 0:219-62.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet systemd.x86_64 0:219-67.el7_7.4 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet systemd-libs.x86_64 0:219-62.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet systemd-libs.x86_64 0:219-67.el7_7.4 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:219-62.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:219-67.el7_7.4 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet teamd.x86_64 0:1.27-5.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet teamd.x86_64 0:1.27-9.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet tuned.noarch 0:2.10.0-6.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet tuned.noarch 0:2.11.0-5.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet tzdata.noarch 0:2018e-3.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet tzdata.noarch 0:2019c-1.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet util-linux.x86_64 0:2.23.2-59.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet util-linux.x86_64 0:2.23.2-61.el7_7.1 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet vim-minimal.x86_64 2:7.4.160-5.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet vim-minimal.x86_64 2:7.4.629-6.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet xfsprogs.x86_64 0:4.5.0-18.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet xfsprogs.x86_64 0:4.5.0-20.el7 sera utilisé
---> Le paquet yum.noarch 0:3.4.3-161.el7.centos sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet yum.noarch 0:3.4.3-163.el7.centos sera utilisé
---> Le paquet yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch 0:1.1.31-50.el7 sera mis à jour
---> Le paquet yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch 0:1.1.31-52.el7 sera utilisé
--> Lancement de la transaction de test
---> Le paquet bind-export-libs.x86_64 32:9.11.4-9.P2.el7 sera installé
---> Le paquet geoipupdate.x86_64 0:2.5.0-1.el7 sera installé
--> Résolution des dépendances terminée

Dépendances résolues
```

and nothing after that I have waited a lot and I have no network problem

Comment: it takes time.works for me. You should probably try again or try by sudo yum update

Comment: @ShiwanginiShishulkar I have logged as root and I have waited 2 hours :(